# XML mapping with typed criteria queries

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria-api, typed

I'm using hibernate with xml mapping I'm trying to run some simple code without much success. I am confident that mapping and classes are correct as I am able to perform other queries using JPQL.

This is a snippet of my code:

```
CriteriaBuilder qb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Report> myquery = qb.createQuery(Report.class);
Root<Report> report = myquery.from(Report.class);
List<Report> result = em.createQuery(myquery).getResultList();
```

And this is the Stack:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: null near line 1, column 29 [select generatedAlias0 from null as generatedAlias0] 
...
...
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: null near line 1, column 29 [select generatedAlias0 from null as generatedAlias0]
...
...
```

Any suggestion?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This might help: [Bug fix related to CriteriaQuery (JPA) when using XML mappings](http://web.archiveorange.com/archive/v/v12Ldzxk09gvWc1UHvpX)

Your problem may actually be related to missing attribute definitions in your persistent and/or root classes. Good luck!

Comment: you're right, I think I will need some luck! It seems to be a damn bug in the libs.